# Paypal API don't want a Delivery Address

Tags: paypal

I'm using secure-hosting as a middleman to process payments from my website which accepts credit card details and has an automatic paypal feature which essentially uses the paypal-api.

It processes payments fine and dandy, however our product isn't supposed to be delivered to the person who purchased it, it is sent to another (or many hundreds of) person(s) whose details are entered on our site by the purchaser.

The problem is that PayPal displays the purchaser's address as the delivery address both when the purchaser is signing into paypal and when they receive an invoice from paypal.

Does anyone know if there is an option to turn off this display of the delivery address/in the email? I've tried adding the no_shipping: '1' and NOSHIPPING=1 field when communicating with paypal but I believe this is to specify that the user doesn't have to supply an address because paypal will have a record of their address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ADDROVERRIDE variable determines whether or not the PayPal pages should display the shipping address set by you in this SetExpressCheckout request, not the shipping address on file with PayPal for this buyer. This would allow you to pass in a shipping address that your buyer enters into a form on your website, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think your method would work so I've flagged it as the answer; I submitted a bug report to our payment processing provider and it turns out their paypal redirecting script doesn't pass on the extra fields I've added for paypal so they are being ignored.